# ¿Existe posibilidad de agregar una imagen a través de un ::before a un path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Quiero añadir una imagen en un extremo a una linea de un mapa que recorre pues una ruta y que está contenida en una etiqueta *g* y le sigue el *path* he intentado hacerle directamente en el diseño y con *before* pero no funciona, qué puedo hacer?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede insertar un svg directamente en un pseudoelento :after o :before;  si quieres hacerlo deberías usar el método Data URI.

Comment: La solución a esto como lo veo es únicamente usando JavaScript, en el caso de que el mapa sea estático si no es estático, ósea el usuario no mueve el mapa de lugar seria perfectamente posible con un par de estilos position en las capas del mapa, también esta la posibilidad, y creo que esta es la mas profesional de usar la propia librería de mapas para ello, como son leaflet o mapbox que perfectamente podría usarse para colocar un svg o image en la posición de coordenadas donde se encuentra la ruta especifica que necesitas. Si brindas mas información te podría ayudar mejor.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es la imagen que quieres añadir?